# проблема при установке psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, парсер, psycopg2

Collecting psycopg2
Using cached psycopg2-2.9.5.tar.gz (384 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [23 lines of output]
running egg_info
creating /private/var/folders/t2/lygb9s9x5dvd64pgmbldnrzr0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-dqu7yixz/psycopg2.egg-info
writing /private/var/folders/t2/lygb9s9x5dvd64pgmbldnrzr0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-dqu7yixz/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/t2/lygb9s9x5dvd64pgmbldnrzr0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-dqu7yixz/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/t2/lygb9s9x5dvd64pgmbldnrzr0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-dqu7yixz/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/t2/lygb9s9x5dvd64pgmbldnrzr0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-dqu7yixz/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

```
  Error: pg_config executable not found.
  
  pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
  containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
  option:
  
      python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
  
  or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
  
  If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
  'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
  
  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
  
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

пробовал апргрейдить pip,а потом установить psycopg2-binary,но все не работает,может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python

Comment: не получилось не одним из тех методов,нашел статьи на хабе, там пишут, что тоже у всех проблемы с установкой на macOS M1

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `pip install psycopg2`
Надо писать `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Откомпилированная версия встанет даже на ту серверную систему, где выключен `bash` и `apt`.